# Get custom parameter from URL in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, email, url, query-string

The gist is:
wordpress sends 'order received' mail to personX, the mail contains a link (which is supposed to set the order status to 'completed'), in the link i put the orderID so i can retrieve that and change the order status with this code:

```
    //-> insert code that last few characters of URL and put that in $order_id

    // Get order
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Update order to completed status
        $order->update_status( 'completed' );
```

When i clicked the link that personX received in the mail (the default woocommerce order received mail + my custom link to a custom page on this printscreen: https://snag.gy/Nyhkcu.jpg) And echo the current URL of the page, it doesnt echo the query_string (the part after ?).

I built the url string like this:

```
<a href="'. admin_url( '/orderConfirmationPage/?orderId=' . absint( $order->id )  ) .'" >
```

Anyway to echo the order id to the page? (so i can try to test the code from the first code block)

Comment: echo $_GET['orderId']; http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: AWESOME!!! that works! thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your string is breaking in echo a tag & admin URL also not proper
change it to like below

```html
$added_string = "?orderId=".$order->id;
$admin_url = get_permalink( get_page_by_title('orderConfirmationPage') );
echo '<a href="'.admin_url( $admin_url ).''.$added_string'" ></a>';
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer i tried it but it took me to the /wp-admin/www.mysite.nl/orderconfirmationpage. So didnt work :/

changed it to this (and works):
 $added_string = "?orderId=".$order->id;
 $admin_url = get_permalink( get_page_by_title('orderconfirmationpage') );

 $link3 .=    '<a href="'. $admin_url . '' . $added_string . '" >';

but still couldnt echo the order ID to the page it redirects to.

Comment: $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
  
  var_dump($actual_link);

Comment: Hi ,
youhave mentioned that your URL will be this "/wp-admin/www.mysite.nl/orderconfirmationpage" & its not work then just remove admin_url() function & make it like href="'.$admin_url.''.$added_string'".

This will work for you.